# Borg and Grob comparison

Tags: opening, analysis, grob, borg

The Grob is a white opening which starts with 1.g4.

The Borg(reversed Grob) is a black opening which goes 1.e4 g5, or 1.d4 g5.

Since White is a tempo up in the Borg, what difference will this make? And what is the significance of the difference?

Comment: 1.e5 is illegal. 1.d4 d5 is the Queen's Pawn Opening not the Borg which would go 1.d4 h6 preparing 2...g5.

Comment: Just dropping in to mention the obvious: that a StarTrek and digital data graphics nerd like me sees "Borg" and "grob" and goes off in entirely different directions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for 1.d4, White's able to win a pawn outright with 2.Bxg5. In 1.e4, the extra tempo gives White better chances to capitalize on Black's dubious move.